# Creation of a simple field failed in MySql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE bdt.transactions ( 
`transaction no`     int UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
data                 date    ,
by                   int  NOT NULL  ,
hours                int  NOT NULL  ,
for                  int  NOT NULL  ,
`transaction type`   set('normale','corso')   NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normale' ,
activity             text  NOT NULL  ,
CONSTRAINT pk_transactions PRIMARY KEY ( `transaction no` ) ) engine=InnoDB
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near  'by                   int  NOT NULL  ,  hours                int
>   NOT NULL  ,  for                  int  NOT NULL    at line 4

With backquotes is now OK

Comment: Your update should be posted as a separate question

Comment: Don't use reserved words as column or table or constraint names. Don't use spaces or dots or other weird characters in names. Then you won't have to use backquotes either.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA done: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71452/problem-with-foreign-keys

Comment: @ypercube I will consider this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`by` is a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), and so is `for`

You should surround reserved words with backquotes (`) if you use them as table or column names. Just to be on the safe side, surround all column names with backquotes

```
CREATE TABLE bdt.transactions ( 
`transaction no`     int UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data`               date    ,
`by`                 int  NOT NULL  ,
`hours`              int  NOT NULL  ,
`for`                int  NOT NULL  ,
`transaction type`   set('normale','corso')   NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normale' ,
`activity`           text  NOT NULL  ,
CONSTRAINT pk_transactions PRIMARY KEY ( `transaction no` ) ) engine=InnoDB
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks, it works. The strange thing was the same error in hours field. Hours is not a reserved word, right?

Comment: Hours is not a reserved word. Are you still getting that error ?

Comment: question updated